# Question about Apache PDFBox and PDF Certification

Tags: pdfbox

We are doing external remote signing using Apache PDFBox, source code is mostly based on the official samples of the Apache PDFBox. We notices some "issues" when we try to sign a document with multiple signatures: They are visible signatures. Input is a document with some signature holders. The flow is:
**Unsigned doc -> sign(graphic_signature1, cert1, unsigned_doc) -> signed_doc_1 -> sign(graphic_signature2, cert2, signed_doc_1) -> signed_doc_2, ....**
The result:

- signed_doc_1: Adobe Acrobat say: Signature is valid, no modification
- signed_doc_2 and subsequent ones: Adobe Acrobat say: The changes that have been made to this document since it was certified are permitted by Certifying party and do not invalidate the signature.

I also read this article:
https://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/11.0/Services/WS92d06802c76abadb-3598a7d812dbeb3dcf3-7ff0.2.html

what I would like to ask:

- Is it actually an issue? (sorry, I am just a developer, I do not know much about the policy for PDF certification)
- If it is an issue, how can it be fixed?

When signing, the following saveIncrementalForExternalSigning has been called:
signatureOptions = new SignatureOptions();
signatureOptions.setVisualSignature(createVisualSignatureTemplate(doc,
signingRequest.getSignatureInfo().getPosition().getPageNumber(), rect, signature));

```
        signatureOptions.setPage(signingRequest.getSignatureInfo().getPosition().getPageNumber());
        doc.addSignature(signature, null, signatureOptions);
        ExternalSigningSupport externalSigning = doc.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(fos);
        // invoke external signature service
        byte[] cmsSignature = sign(externalSigning.getContent());
        // set signature bytes received from the service and save the file
        externalSigning.setSignature(cmsSignature);
```

Edited: I was able to "fix" the issue by comment the line of code to call setMDPPermission(doc, signature, 2). (In the Apache PDFBox signature sample). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Posted by the OP:

> I was able to "fix" the issue by comment the line of code to call
> setMDPPermission(doc, signature, 2). (In the Apache PDFBox signature
> sample). Thanks!